# SparkSQL groupby to create nested records

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have information of the form (obviously fake, but serves the purpose):

```
| User | Country |
|------|---------|
| A    | Sweden  |
| A    | Sweden  |
| A    | London  |
| B    | Spain   |
| B    | Denmark |
| B    | Brazil  |
| C    | India   |
```

This is available as a dataframe in spark. I was looking to use spark (and maybe SparkSQL) to calculate a frequency map for each user.

```
(A => Map((Sweden, 2), (London, 1)))
(B => Map((Spain, 1), (Brazil, 1), (Denmark, 1)))
(C => Map((India, 1)))
```

So far I've gotten as far as:

```
(A => (Sweden, 2))
(A => (London, 1))
(B => (Spain, 1))
(B => (Brazil, 1))
(B => (Denmark, 1))
(C => (India, 1))
```

by using the following query:

```
SELECT user, country, COUNT(country) as frequency
FROM information
GROUP BY user, country
```

but the problem with this is that I end up with 6 rows instead of 3. Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply another `groupBy/agg` to aggregate `struct(Country, Frequency)` using `collect_list`, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("A", "Sweden"), ("A", "Sweden"), ("A", "London"),
  ("B", "Spain"), ("B", "Denmark"), ("B", "Brazil"),
  ("C", "India")
).toDF("User", "Country")

df.
  groupBy("User", "Country").agg(count("Country").as("Frequency")).
  groupBy("User").agg(collect_list(struct("Country", "Frequency")).as("Country_Counts")).
  show(false)
// +----+------------------------------------+
// |User|Country_Counts                      |
// +----+------------------------------------+
// |B   |[[Denmark,1], [Brazil,1], [Spain,1]]|
// |C   |[[India,1]]                         |
// |A   |[[London,1], [Sweden,2]]            |
// +----+------------------------------------+
```

Note that the first `groupBy/agg` transformation is equivalent to your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

After this, you need to group by user and collect the map of country and frequency. Below code should be helpful.

```
//Creating Test Data
val df = Seq(("A", "Sweden"), ("A", "Sweden"), ("A", "London"), ("B", "Spain"), ("B", "Denmark"), ("B", "Brazil"), ("C", "India"))
  .toDF("user", "country")

df.show(false)
+----+-------+
|user|country|
+----+-------+
|A   |Sweden |
|A   |Sweden |
|A   |London |
|B   |Spain  |
|B   |Denmark|
|B   |Brazil |
|C   |India  |
+----+-------+

df.registerTempTable("information")

val joinMap = spark.udf.register( "joinMap" , (values: Seq[Map[String,Long]]) => values.flatten.toMap )

val resultDF = spark.sql("""SELECT user, joinMap(collect_list(map(country, frequency))) as frequencyMap
                           |From ( SELECT user, country, COUNT(country) as frequency
                           |FROM information
                           |GROUP BY user, country ) A
                           |GROUP BY user""".stripMargin)

resultDF.show(false)
+----+------------------------------------------+
|user|frequencyMap                              |
+----+------------------------------------------+
|A   |Map(Sweden -> 2, London -> 1)             | 
|B   |Map(Spain -> 1, Denmark -> 1, Brazil -> 1)|
|C   |Map(India -> 1)                           |
+----+------------------------------------------+
```

If you want the final result as Map, use the UDF. Without the UDF, you will get it as a List of Map.